# How should I proceed to make a program that, when given three sides of the triangle in an array, will determine if they can make a valid triangle?

Tags: c

Given three sides of a triangle. I have to determine by writing a program using C language whether I can make a valid triangle or not using these three sides of the triangle. So how should I proceed ?

We all know that a triangle is a geometric shape with three positive sides. However, any given three sides won’t necessarily form a triangle. There is a formula/condition that the biggest side of a triangle is less than the sum of other two sides of the triangle. If this formula/condition is satisfied then we can make a valid triangle using those three sides. Now I have to make a program to find out whether I can make a valid triangle or not using those three positive sides. So, first I have to find out which is the biggest value among the three sides. And for this purpose I have to make a simple program like this…..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{

   int i,side[3],max;

   for( i  = 0; i < 3; i++ )

      scanf("%d",&side[i]);

      max = side[0];

      for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){

             if( side[i] > max )

             max = side[i];
    }

    return 0;

    }
```

Now I have get the biggest sides of the triangle through the above program. But now I have got stuck here that next how can I make a program to define whether the biggest side is less than the sum of other two sides of that triangle.

Suppose if we use three different variables rather than the three size array and if we know that the biggest side of triangle is `b` then simply we will use this condition

```
    if ( b < a + c)
        printf("Valid\n");
    else
        printf("In-valid\n");
```

but as I used an array here rather than three different variables, I can’t write this code simply to determine whether the triangle will be valid or not. Using an array, it is simply easy to find out the biggest side of the triangle but using array I can’t check the condition of forming triangle here.

So in this circumstance what should I do?

Comment: Sort the array...

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete and what is there may have some other errors (possibly uninitalized memory) in it that will prevent you from realizing the proper answer. You will need to debug your code some.  I would encourage you to read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It looks like quite a few people here could probably do with reading http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1 as well...

Comment: It is more a math problem than a C programming problem. Solve the math first!

Comment: One of the lengths could also be `0` ..

Comment: You were able to write code to find the max -- can you write code to find the min? How about code to find a side that is between max and min? For extra credit, decide what to do if all 3 sides are equal, or if two sides are the same length.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than saving max as the VALUE of the largest side, try saving max as the index of the value instead.  Then since you know which element in the array contains the max value, just add the other 2 elements and compare to the value pointed to by max.

Answer (score 4):

While it's true that the triangle inequality is `c < a + b`, this is equivalent to `2c < a + b + c`, which is a lot easier to do. You can calculate the running total without knowing the max, and by the time you get to the end you will already know the max. See the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i, side[3], max = -1, total = 0;

  for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&side[i]);
    max = side[i] > max ? side[i] : max;
    total += side[i];
  }

  if (2 * max < total) {
    printf("Valid\n");
  } else {
    printf("In-valid\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

<sub>[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/gfihjT)</sub>

As an aside, I recommend using curly braces for all your code blocks, as it makes the code easier to follow, and using proper indentation. `? :` is the [ternary operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_sizeof_operator.htm), which is a way to do quick if statements in line.